# Why is the bevel crossing on this edge?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, bevel

Every time I try to bevel this edge on the left that was made identical to the other edge on the right, it either crosses or only bevels one side of the edge. I have recreated the edge from scratch a few times and I get the same result every time. I made sure there's no doubled vertices and I cant find any weird geometry that is causing the problem either. Just doesn't make sense that one side would work fine while the other glitches out. [Project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dXKMQg_R5FUJoJWsh5hYSmc9KViwY1YG/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see if you display the faces orientation, you have flipped normals, so before the bevel, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]